# Difference between the following sentences

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> I drove down there.
>
> I drove up there.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I live to the North of, or at a higher elevation than my destination, I might say:

> I drove down there.

Similarly, if I live to the South of, or at a lower elevation than my destination, I might say:

> I drove up there.

However, both expressions are highly idiomatic in English, and are often used  to connote merely *driving,* without any reference to compass or sea level.

Comment: Or "down into the valley" or "up into the hills".

Comment: @user3169 +1 Incorporated...

Comment: Yeah... pretty much. Sometimes, I'll say "up" and then realize I'm talking about a place that's south of me and I'll correct myself... but usually I just use them interchangeably.